# Java error (package java.nio.file does not exist import java.nio.file.*;)

Tags: java, file-io, import, nio

I am new and learning Java.  I tried running the following application in Netbeans 7.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.StrandardOpenOption.*;

public class FileOut
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Path file = Paths.get("C:\\Java\\Chapter.13\\Grades.txt");
        String s = "ABCDF";
        byte[] data = s.getBytes();
        OutputStream output = null;
        try
        {
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(file.newOutputStream(CREATE));
            output.write(data);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Message: " + e);
        }

    }
}
```

and when I compile the app I get the following error message:

```
package java.nio.file does not exist import java.nio.file.*;
```

The error displays on both of these lines.

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.StrandardOpenOption.*;
```

What do I need to do to get this to work?  I would appreciate any help.

Thank you,
Joe

Comment: This is nothing to do with HTML or Ruby - please keep tags relevant

Comment: What is the CLASSPATH entry in your environment variables? It needs to be set to something like `C:\<PATH_TO_JDK7>\jdk1.7.0\bin`

Answer (score 11):

Sounds like you are using a Java version 6 or lower. The java.nio.file package and classes were added as part of Java 7. Try running the following to verify you have Java 7 installed.

```
java -version
```

Comment: I have version 1.6.

c:\>java -version
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: I have updated the version to 7 and added the CLASSPATH.  I am trying to update the netbeans.conf file to the new version but when I try and save it, it says "confirm this file is not open or being used".  I have netbeans closed.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

You've got a small typo in your include. It should read:

```
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
```

The package `java.nio.file.*` should exist in Java SE 7. Please check whether you are really using the Java 7 Compiler.